# Data comes out as one text ,I want to divide the data into course name, description, so on

Tags: python, sql, database, selenium, parsing

```
     'element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="block_content"]')
    with open('asin_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        f.write(element.text+"\n")
        

    print(element.text)
    
        
    driver.back()'
```

I need to divide the data of element into the csv file

Comment: Can you add the content of `element.text`?

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't uploaded element.text (which would be helpful). I assume that there is an array of elements.

You should do:

```
elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="block_content"]')
with open('asin_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    for element in elements:
        f.write(element.text+"\n")
        print(element.text)
```